# Having trouble removing punctuation and upper case letters? (Beginner)

Tags: python

Awful programmer here. For a class assignment I have to take words from a text document, count them, and order them. I am having trouble erasing the punctuation and replacing the upper case letters with lower ones. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
docwords={}
doc=raw_input("Please enter the name of a text file: ")
docread=open(doc, 'r')
doclist=[]



def main():
    for x in docread:
        words = x.split()
    for word in words:
        doclist.append(word)

def wordcount():
    main()
    for counter in doclist:
        docwords[counter] = docwords.get(counter,0) + 1

wordcount()
docread.close()
for p in sorted(docwords):
    print p, "-->", docwords[p]
```

Comment: There is a `Counter` class in the standard library that is useful for doing the actual counting of words.

Answer (score 2):

To start, your `main` is not doing what you want.  Notice what the `for` loops do: first, you read each line, one at a time, and assign a list of the words in each line to `words`.  But you've just been overwriting `words` over and over again, so now `words` is the list of words in the last line.  Now, you put those words into `doclist`.  Think about how for loop nesting and fix this section first:

```
def main():
    for x in docread:
        words = x.split()
    for word in words:
        doclist.append(word)
```

Now, we can move on to the parts you're missing.  Python has a lot of useful libraries.  For lowercasing a string, try looking here: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower.  For getting rid of punctuation, you might find this function helpful for determining whether a character is a letter: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha.

Since its homework, I'm hesitant to give away code.  Otherwise you won't learn it.  Say something if you get stuck again.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the lower case and the punctuation to work. The for loop was a typo and I apologize.

Comment: @user1044868 No need to apologize.  You can edit the typo out of your post if you want to fix the record.  Since you're new here, I'll also point out that you should accept answers to your questions, particularly if you want future questions answered.

Answer (score 1):

**Erasing punctuation**

One option is to the regular expression module's re.sub function. In this case, I will remove all characters that are not alphanumeric or spaces.

```
import re
s = "It's ok"
print re.sub('[^\w ]','',s)
Its ok
```

**Lower case**

A straight-forward lower function of the string object.

```
>>> 'Its ok'.lower()
its ok
```

Answer (score 0):

This could really all be done in 1 line (prompt, open, read, split, strip and lower withing list comp):

```
words = [word.strip("!\"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~").lower() for word in open(raw_input("Please enter the name of a text file: ").strip(), 'r').read().replace("'", "").split()]
```

Then print stats:

```
print "Word count: %d" % len(words)
for p in sorted(words):
    print %s --> %s" % (p, words[p])
```

Or, the long(er):

```
docwords={}
doc=raw_input("Please enter the name of a text file: ")
docread=open(doc, 'r')
doclist=[]

def main():

    for x in docread:
        doclist.extend([word.strip("!\"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~").replace("'", "").lower() for word in x.split()])

def wordcount():
    main()
    for counter in doclist:
        docwords[counter] = docwords.get(counter,0) + 1

wordcount()
docread.close()
for p in sorted(docwords):
    print p, "-->", docwords[p]
```