# Word frequency in a text document excluding punctuations

Tags: python, string, replace

I am trying to write a program that will read all of the words in a text document named, "GlassDog.txt". Once the program reads the words it will need to remove all of the punctuations, as well as, making all of the letters lowercase. Then when the program is finished with all of this I would like it to print the word that it found and how many times it was used in the document.

Here is my code so far:

```
def run():
    count = {} 
    for w in open('GlassDog.txt').read().split(): 
        if w in count: 
            count[w] += 1 
        else: 
            count[w] = 1

    for word, times in count.items(): 
        print ("%s was found %d times" % (word, times)) 

run()
```

This code will read and display the words and the frequency of the words. However, I could not find a way on how to implement a code that would remove the punctuations and replace the uppercase letters with lowercase letters. This question has probably been asked a few times, I just couldn't seem to find anything that does specifically what I am looking for. I apologize if this is a repeat question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having trouble removing punctuation and upper case letters? (Beginner)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116882/having-trouble-removing-punctuation-and-upper-case-letters-beginner)

Comment: str function `.lower()` will convert your string to lower case. Eg. `'TEST'.lower()` gives `'test'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could user .lower() on the string to convert to lowercase before the if block and for matching only alphanumeric try a regular expression take a look specifically at \w

Comment: This doesn't address punctuation

Comment: The regular expression part does.  I belive \w will give him what he wants, if not he can change the pattern to [a-z] or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

def just_alnum(s):
    return ''.join(c for c in s if c.isalnum())

with open('GlassDog.txt', 'r') as f:
    counts = Counter(just_alnum(w.lower()) for w in f.read().split())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>msg = "Hello,World!"
>>>msg = msg.lower() #convert into all lowercase
>>>print msg
hello,world!
>>>msg = filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), msg) #remove every character that isn't a letter
>>>print msg
helloworld
```

Answer (score 0):

This method is certainly not the most optimized, but I think it is robust :

```
>>> msg = "A   very42 dirty__ string ©."
# Replace all non alphabetical characters (maybe you want isalnum() instead)
>>> msg = map(lambda x: x if x.isalpha() else ' ', msg)
# Concat splitted chars
>>> msg = ''.join(msg)
# Avoid multiple spaces
>>> msg = ' '.join(msg.split())
>>> msg
'A very dirty string'
```

On a huge and heterogeneous input, it will consume a lot of ressources so, if you want something more optimized, you should adapt it, according to the constraints you know about the input file (by example: Is the punctuation always surrounded by spaces?).

Besides, you can do all this stuff in one-line, but it can be hard to understand for the next reader of your code...